# Reconnecting Emulator to Eclipse

Tags: android, ide

My main problem with developing in Android is that the emulator seems to continually get disconnected from eclipse. This always happens the 2-3 time I try to upload my .apk from eclipse without rebooting the emulator. Eclipse indicates this with an empty DDMS ->Device section and logcat stays blank - sometimes I'm not sure if the new code made it on the device.

The only fix I have for this is to shut down eclipse, and restart it.  With the restarting of Eclipse, on top of the emulator boot time, I can't get any momentum going in my development.

Is there a way to reconnect the emulator to eclipse without having to restart Eclipse or even the Emulator?

**Update:** There were a couple of answers that helped, particularly "reset adb" or Kill-server ->  connect adb. However, sometimes even that is troublesome.

I am going to try Pentium10's suggestion of hooking up my G1 and using it as an emulator, but for now, I have found that if I don't see my logcat going, and the emulator is working (This is my biggest problem, because I am outputting all my debugging messages to log) then I can open up CMD and type **adb logcat**. This streams the log into the command window. Not nicely color coded, but nice enough for me to find my problems...

Comment: This happens to me periodically as well but usually only when I'm popping around between multiple emulators and attaching/removing my phone. If you check out "adb devices" on the command line, do you still see your devices listed there?

Comment: @Thomas - Honestly, I'm not sure how to do an Android command line statement. I did, however, find an adb entry under processes in windows task manager. I killed it and restarted Eclipse, but logcat is still coming up blank when the emulator boots up. Sometimes, I have to restart the computer because I can't figure out which process is the monkey wrench.

Comment: Try adding the Devices view (from Android) as a new tab next to LogCat and selecting your application and hitting the Stop button before you recompile. Since I've been doing this I haven't had the problem (although to be honest since I've set it up in Ubuntu I haven't had nearly as many problems in general as I had with Windows)

Comment: It should be in the folder your SDK is in, under the subdirectory tools. adb.exe.  Navigate there and run it to check out the command line version of the tools.

Comment: you may want to try coloredlogcat.py - http://jsharkey.org/blog/2009/04/22/modifying-the-android-logcat-stream-for-full-color-debugging/

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In eclipse go to Window->Show View->Other->Android->Devices. When your application is run go to this tab and you will see the emulator. If your emulator becomes unresponsive, in the devices tab you will see a down arrow at the right. Click the arrow and a context menu shows up. Hit the option Reset adb.

Just had to do this and it worked beautifully, but it did require you to reset the emulator - though I didn't wait to see if it reconnected on its own.

Comment: You can do methodin's suggestion - and then run adb logcat from CMD without shutting down the emulator. Works most of the time - which is why I marked this answer as correct.

Answer (score 5):

Try to call 'Reset adb' menu item from DDMS > Devices tab. It helps me in this case.

Comment: I see "Update Heap" "Drop HPROF File" "Update Threads".... a couple more, but no Reset adb?

Comment: @cinqoTimo - in that row of icons the last one on the right is 'View Menu' (a little arrow icon). Select it to see the menu items, one of the menu items is 'Reset adb'.

Answer (score 1):

At most of the time you don't need to restart the emulator.

AFAIK the only workaround for this is to restart Eclipse (I always use this), or use a real phone.

Comment: I have a G1, and I've tried it, but Uploading and installing the .apk manually is no fun either - plus, you can't see the log.

Comment: You need to recognize the phone with your computer and connect with adb, search for some tutorials about this. My phone when plugged in shows up as a device in Eclipse, and when I hit Run it just works as it was the emulator. No manual install stuff done by me.

Comment: yes, but doing this still does not allow you to see you're debugging or crash reports I believe, and if you can, I'd love to know how, but I've yet to look into it, so its definitely possible

Comment: it works as same as emulator. The debug logs shows up in Eclipse in the same place.

Answer (score 1):

Try adb kill-server, followed by an adb connect

Answer (score 0):

I've had luck reconnecting to the disconnected emulator by entering an adb-over-tcp command line which you can look up in the docs.  I think the address and port to use are the ones in the title bar of the emulator window, if not try the next higher port.   Once it's back in adb devices eclipse should use it.

Answer (score 0):

in terminal:

```
$adb kill-server && adb start-server
```